# How to use find -iregex OR (|) operator?

Tags: regex, find, syntax

Uninstalled an application, but it continues to pop up whenever I try to interact with file types that it used to be associated with.

As usual, `find` has been invaluable in finding and eliminating leftovers. But I noticed that I couldn't seem to get the regex OR operator to work the way I expected it to.

Some things I tried that didn't work:

```
find / -iregex '(.*crossover.*)|(.*codeweavers.*)'          2>/dev/null
find / -iregex '(^.*crossover.*$)|(^.*codeweavers.*$)'      2>/dev/null
find / -iregex '\(.*crossover.*\)\|\(.*codeweavers.*\)'     2>/dev/null
find / -iregex '\(^.*crossover.*$\)\|\(^.*codeweavers.*$\)' 2>/dev/null
```

Some things I tried that did work:

```
find / -iregex '\(.*crossover.*\)' 2>/dev/null
find / -iregex '^.*crossover.*$'   2>/dev/null
find / -iregex '.*crossover.*'     2>/dev/null
```

I was under the impression that if `'\(.*crossover.*\)'`, returns a match..
Then `'\(.*crossover.*\)\|whatever'` should too.

What's the correct syntax?

Comment: Works for me. Linux Mint in VirtualBox.

Comment: In my Debian 9 the first two don't work. The rest does.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you escape pipe it (as your first two examples do wrong) the rest should work.

Tested:

> I have the files
>   **/home/gaston/.viminfo**
>   and **/home/gaston/.vim**

`find ~ -iregex '.*/\.vim\|.*/\.viminfo'` yields

```
/home/gaston/.viminfo
/home/gaston/.vim
```

and `find ~ -iregex '.*/\.vim\|s;dlfkgj;slfjgs'` yields:

```
/home/gaston/.vim
```